# How to display chosen directory on the same window?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my current Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os


root = Tk()
root.title("SIGN OFF")
root.minsize(840, 800)



# Add a grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = StringVar(root)

# Dictionary with options
options = glob.glob("C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/[![enter image description here][1]][1]work/data/to-do/*.jpg*")
choices = {*options}
tkvar.set('...To Sign Off...') # set the default option

popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text="Choose your sign off here:").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)

# on change dropdown value
def change_dropdown(*args):
    directory = (tkvar.get())
    os.startfile(directory)

def open():
    img = change_dropdown()
    photo = ImageTK.PhotoImage(img)

    root.label2 = Label(image=photo)
    root.label2.image = photo
    root.label2.grid(column = 3 , row = 5)

Button(mainframe, text="Open", command = change_dropdown).grid(row = 3, column = 1)



root.mainloop()
```

And here is the output:

[image: IMG 1]

When I choose that Directory as shown on the image, when I click Ok, it opens the image on a separate window. How do I get it to open just on the side of the same window? Like, preview sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question — and think what you really want to do is display a chosen **image** in the same window (not a directory). Your current code is opening the image in a separate windows because it displays it with a `os.startfile()` call in the `change_dropdown()` callback function, which opens whatever application is associated with `.jpg` file on your system — which on my system happens to be the `Windows Photo Viewer`.

Anyway, here's code that I think at least accomplishes the basics of what you're trying to accomplish:

```
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SIGN OFF")
root.minsize(840, 800)

# Add a grid
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)

directory = "C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg"))
tkvar.set('...To Sign Off...') # set the default option

popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
tk.Label(mainframe, text="Choose your sign off here:").grid(row=1, column=1)
popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)

label2 = tk.Label(mainframe, image=None)
label2.grid(row=4, column=1)

# On change dropdown callback.
def change_dropdown(*args):
    """ Updates label2 image. """
    imgpath = tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)

tk.Button(mainframe, text="Open", command=change_dropdown).grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of it running on my system after I selected an image from the dropdown `OptionMenu` and then clicked on the <kbd>Open</kbd> `Button`:

[image: screenshot of script running and display an image in the same window]

Comment: How can the scroll bar be implemented if the img is too large? I know how to resize it. But scroll bar is new to me.